# alertTime and Timevalue refresh

Tags: vba, refresh, alert

I am using `alertTime` and `RefreshAll` to update data, but instead of refreshing at the `timevalue' I want, it refreshes randomly.

Here is the code:

```
Sub Macro1()
    'Macro1 Macro

    alertTime = Now + TimeValue("00:01:00") 'hh:mm:ss
    Application.OnTime alertTime, "Macro1"

    Dim LTime1 As Date, LTime2 As Date
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
    Dim USDJPY As Worksheet, Allrates As Worksheet, EURGBP As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long

    Set Allrates = Sheets("Allrates")
    Set EURUSD = Sheets("EURUSD")
    Set EURGBP = Sheets("EURGBP")

    LTime1 = TimeValue("15:30:00")
    LTime2 = TimeValue("15:32:00")

    If Range("P20") = LTime1 Then
        Allrates.Range("B18").Copy EURGBP.Cells(EURGBP.Range("B10000").End(xlUp).Row + 1, 2)
    End If

    If Range("P20") = LTime2 Then
        Allrates.Range("B18").Copy EURGBP.Cells(EURGBP.Range("B10000").End(xlUp).Row + 1, 2)
    End If

    ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Is alertTime getting set to a proper time value?  I ask because it appears commented out and may not be in the actual code.

Also, is another procedure also running when it should?  Also cut, copy and find could be occurring at the time it is running.  In any case, it will run when the thread is free or if it's longer than 30 seconds it will cancel.  [check this out](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196165.aspx)

Comment: thats the code. when it meets time condition LTime1 and LTime2 i want to  copy paste some values. but i want the time step every 1 minute, otherwise it keeps pasting all the time. thanks vm Jimmy help